# Como acessar um elemento dentro de outro elemento HTML com JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como acessar um elemento dentro de outro elemento através do id usando JavaScript puro.

Atualmente uso `getElementsByTagName('a')` mas como no meu projeto vou ter vários elementos do mesmo tipo, não vai ser usual.

Também conheço o `getElementsByClassName('huebr')` mas o mesmo não é suportado no IE9.

Ambiente para testes:
http://jsfiddle.net/douglas1551/mgy6z0uo/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Seletores a la jQuery:

Estão [disponíveis no document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) e em [todos os elementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector); funcionam de maneira similar ao jQuery, e são bem suportados pelos browsers mais modernos. No IE, [pelo que consta](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), estão disponíveis a partir da versão 8.
A string de parâmetro deve conter um ou mais seletores CSS separados por vírgula, apesar de que em minhas experiências seletores mais complexos (com pseudo-seletores) falharam.

```
// captura apenas a PRIMEIRA tag <a> da página:
var a = document.querySelector("a"); // retorna apenas o elemento encontrado (ou null)

// captura, dentro de 'a', TODOS (All) os elementos com classe "classeA" ou "classeB":
var b = a.querySelectorAll(".classeA, .classeB"); // retorna um array de filhos
```

### Array de elementos filhos

Estão disponíveis em todos os elementos que contenham filhos; contém todos os elementos filhos (que não sejam nós puro-texto).

```
var c = b.children[0]; // exemplo de uso
```

### Array de nós (texto/elemento) filhos

Estão disponíveis em todos os elementos, e contém todos os elementos filhos (textuais ou não).

```
var d = c.childNodes[1]; // exemplo de uso
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, vai ser extremamente util o querySelector citado. Valew!

Answer (score 4):

Vamos supor um elemento que você recuperou com Javascript puro, chamado `foo`. Você pode obter `foo` pelos métodos que já conhece. Por exemplo:

```
// experimento no fonte desta página!
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("post-text")[0];
```

Você pode usar as propriedades [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) ou [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes). A quantidade de elementos filhos vai estar em [`childElementcount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.childElementCount). Você pode usar essas propriedades da seguinte forma:

```
var numberOfKids = foo.childElementCount;
```

Lembre-se de que o retorno de métodos certos métodos como `getElementsByClassName` pode ser um  array. Nesse caso cada elemento do array vai ter as propriedades que mencionei.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Renan, mas o IE9 não oferece suporte ao getElementsByClassName no meu caso realmente vou utilizar o getElementsByTagName('a')[0] tenho acesso simples aos elementos. Valew